# What is the cheapest way to move money from the United States to Canada?

Tags: united-states, canada, foreign-exchange, money-transfer, international-transfer

I live and work in the United States but I have several loans in Canada that I need to pay on a regular basis, so I'm constantly moving money to Canada.

Right now, I have an American Royal Bank account linked to my Canadian Royal Bank account. I transfer money from my Chase Bank account to my American Royal Bank account. Then, a few days later when the transfer has taken place, I transfer it between the two Royal Bank accounts.

I'm wondering if there's a cheaper way for me to move my money, maybe with a better exchange rate or less fees. When I first looked into this, I remember there being a significant fee for an international wire transfer, but maybe the exchange is better?

Right now, I'm moving about $1000 every month or two. I'm wondering what I'll do if I get a big bonus and I want to move ten or twenty thousand dollars at once. Maybe there's a dollar amount when it becomes cheaper to use another method?

Comment: There are many non-bank transfer companies around that are cheaper.  I tend to use [USForex](https://www.usforex.com/). They give better exchange rates for the currencies I'm interested in (AUD/USD/EUR) and zero fees. They just make their money on the rate (though less than any of my banks do).

Comment: Agree strongly with Peter -- you can find better exchange rates than most banks offer by looking for a third-party service like USForex.

Comment: That's really more of an answer than a comment, Peter K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't familiar with [Norbert's Gambit](http://www.finiki.org/wiki/Norbert's_Gambit), it's worth looking at. This is a mechanism using a Canadian brokerage account to simultaneously execute one stock trade in CAD and one in USD. The link I provided claims that it only starts potentially making sense somewhere in the 10,000+ range.

Answer (score -1):

No fees: Write a check. Deposit it into the other bank.

Comment: Depositing a foreign currency check at a Canadian bank will result in 2.5% to 3.5% hidden fee from the market midpoint. The banks will automatically convert USD check to CAD at horrible rates.

Comment: Even if there weren't hidden fees, this solution wouldn't work for me because, as I stated, I live in the United States.